# Disable specific event

Tags: excel

I am using a button to toggle Application.EnableEvents:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Enable Events"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Disable Events"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

How can I disable `SelectionChange` without disabling `Change`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you'd want to disable `SelectionChange` or what that would do?

If you have code in that section, you could just wrap it in an if statement.

```
' Insert the following code into a new module: Module1
Public SelectionChange_Enabled As Boolean

' Example of your Worksheet_SelectionChange event's code
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If SelectionChange_Enabled = True Then
    ' Your code
    End If
End Sub
```

You can change the value of `SelectionChange_Enabled` to enable or disable the code inside the event.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! Now I can't accidentally trigger `SelectionChange` when I want to use `Change`.